# trying to add CSP header but it modifies the display of the website

Tags: html, security, meta-tags, content-security-policy

I'm trying to add CSP header, but it changes how my website is displayed. This is the code for the first two pictures:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src '*'; style-src 'self' cdn.jsdelivr.net; script-src *; object-src *; img-src *; media-src *; report-src *; connect-src *">
    
    <title>Euskor&oacute;scopo</title>  
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabla_inicio.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-image: url('images/background.webp'); background-size: cover; color: white;">
...
</body>
```

[image]
[image]

The code for the last two pictures:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *">
    <title>Web Login</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/format_messages.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>

</head>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not a fix but you are inconsistent with your usage of the closing slash `/>`. Note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all other HTML tags.

Comment: Open your browser developer tools. Look at the Console. It will tell you what has been blocked by the CSP. Add rules to allow them or change the CSS which uses those URLs to use something you are allowing.

Comment: I get the following and don't know how to act: localhost/:25 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-bp0tBT9srApZNVSnLal8esmwmT/zyR6xH2N3/WTGDl4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to understand how CSP works first before enabling it blindly. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP.

In your code, you are applying inline styles. These are styles that are injected directly into your HTML tags. The Content-Security-Policy does not allow this unless explicitly enabled.

So, to fix your code, either add `'unsafe-inline'` (with quotation marks) like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src '*'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdn.jsdelivr.net; script-src *; object-src *; img-src *; media-src *; report-src *; connect-src *">
```

Or, a much better approach: move your CSS to a different file or style tag.

That being said, the CSP header you have right now doesn't make a lot of sense. You're basically only restricting the style origin, and not restricting anything else (like script). CSP is used to restrict the possible damage that can be done when an XSS exploit occurs, so restricting only the style origin isn't going to help you with that.

Comment: Thanks! And what about using nonce? I have tried this https://content-security-policy.com/nonce/ but it didn't work